# How to install this source from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

I tried to instal dalecook actionwebservice (this is updated datanoise's version 2.3.2 to 2.3.5), with command:

```
sudo gem install actionwebservice --source gems.github.com
```

I tried too: dalecook-actionwebservice instead actionwebservice or http://github.com/dalecook/actionwebservice instead gem.github.com

and resut is the same

```
ERROR: github.com/dalecook/actionwebservice.git/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'actionwebservice' (>= 0) in any repository
```

How to install this source on my OSX?

github.com/dalecook/actionwebservice

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

gems.github.com is no longer running. This is where something like [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) comes in handy.  With Bundler you would just add

```
gem 'actionwebservice', :git => "git://github.com/dalecook/actionwebservice.git"
```

to you Gemfile and run `bundle install` to use that specific fork of the gem.